# Qubes OS Switch from Windows

Tags: windows, file-transfer, qubes

Currently being on Windows 10 and wanting to transfer to Linux, I have found Qubes, and think it to be a good starting point for security and usability. But whatever, not the point.

Is there a way to move my current Windows 10 OS into Qubes without moving everything to an external hard drive or another computer (this is an option, though). I have all of my projects, pics, etc., on a hard drive; my Windows OS, games, and app data are on an SSD.
My current thought is to partition my SSD, put Qubes on the new partition, then run Qubes, create a Windows 10 OS virtualization and move as much info over as I can. Then transfer the hard drive (or the part of it that has all the Windows stuff on it), into the virtualization (is this possible?). Then split my SSD and hard drive into multiple parts, one of each for each of the OS.

How much of this is fantasy, and what is actually possible? But most importantly will I be able to keep my files (pics, work files, documents, etc.) if I want to move to Qubes without having to use a dual boot?